# Inner join with 3 tables in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, join, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to do an inner join with 3 tables in Visual Studio but I am getting an error. When I do the inner join with only 2 tables it works.

Here is my code for 3 tables:

```
"select b.bidID, b.userID, u.userFirstName, u.userLastName, c.clientName, b.productName, b.openingDate, b.status
from Bid b
inner join Client c on b.clientID = c.clientID
inner join User u on b.userID = u.userID
where b.clientID = '" + cId + "' ";
```

with 2 tables:

```
"select b.bidID, b.userID, c.clientName, b.productName, b.openingDate, b.status
from Bid b
inner join Client c on b.clientID = c.clientID
where b.clientID = '" + cId + "' ";
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  How are you executing the query -- EF? NHibernate? Some other ORM?  What database are you using?

Comment: Your SQL statement is susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: What is the error that you're receiving?

Answer (score 5):

`user` is reserved keyword in MSSQL.
Use it with square brackets like this `[user]`

```
select b.bidID ,b.userID , u.userFirstName, u.userLastName ,c.clientName , b.productName , b.openingDate,b.status 
from Bid b 
inner join Client c on b.clientID=c.clientID 
inner join [User] u on b.userID=u.userID 
where b.clientID='" + cId + "' "
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell since you didn't include the error you are getting but my guess would be that you are getting an error because User is a keyword in SQL Server.  Try to change User to [User] and see if your error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following SQL query

```
select b.bidID ,b.userID , u.userFirstName, u.userLastName, c.clientName , b.productName , b.openingDate,b.status 
from ([Bid] b inner join [Client] c on b.clientID=c.clientID ) 
inner join [User] u on (b.userID=u.userID) where b.clientID='" + cId + "' ;
```